# Page in localhost keeps loading

Tags: google-chrome, cakephp, browser

This is not exactly a problem, but only something that made me curious.

When I open a page (index.php of cakephp to be more precise) in chrome, even though it loads correctly, it seems as if it is still loading something. The content of the page doesn't change, but the rolling circle keeps rolling. In mozilla this doesn't happen.

I've seen this behavior with other pages as well (that reside in my local machine), but I can't seem to find any connection between them.

So I was wondering if anyone has noticed or knows something about this.

(in case it is relevant)

Operating system - Linux mint

Chrome version - Version 39.0.2171.95

Comment: If you press F12 in chrome, and look in the network tab. Do you see something that is not fully loaded?

Comment: @WvanRij : No, I don't see anything that isn't fully loaded. That's what surprises me.

Comment: common issue I find when developing. Reboot chrome - problem sorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I found this behaviour also while developing. First thought it could be a remote script loading, like jquery. Closing and reopening the tab fixes the issue.

Comment: Restart machine; also works